# XSLT sort by attribute and attribute value (with exclude)

Tags: sorting, xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0, alphabetical

I have a following XML code:

```
<module>
    <component>
        <output>
        <output-test>
        <exclude-output/>
        <orderEntry type="specific"/>
        <orderEntry type="other"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module1"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module3"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module2"/>
        <orderEntry type="library" name="library1"/>
        <orderEntry type="library" name="library3"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module4"/>
        <orderEntry type="library" name="library2"/>
    </component>
</module>
```

I would like to have the output:

```
<module>
    <component>
        <output>
        <output-test>
        <exclude-output/>
        <orderEntry type="specific"/>
        <orderEntry type="other"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module1"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module2"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module3"/>
        <orderEntry type="module" module-name="module4"/>
        <orderEntry type="library" name="library1"/>
        <orderEntry type="library" name="library2"/>
        <orderEntry type="library" name="library3"/>
    </component>
</module>
```

Comment: What is the logic of your sort order? Why does `specific` come before `other`? -- Also please state XSLT 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: For the `orderEntry` elements : `specific` and `other` are two elements that must be before the others. The logic: I have modules and I have a XML file for the dependencies. For a better visibility, I would like to sort all dependencies in the XML file.

Comment: First, `specific` and `other`. Then, I have to sort the others `orderEntry` by type then by library.

Comment: Then why does "library" come after "module"?

Comment: Please don't ask two unrelated questions in one post. SO doesn't allow more than one answer to be accepted. I'm simply going to delete your second question.

Comment: If you sort by `type`, then `module` will come **after** `library` in alphabetical order. Anyway, please fix your input and the output so that they are well-formed XML documents - right now you have several elements missing their end-tags.

Comment: How to sort `orderEntry` knowing that `orderEntry` with `specific` and `other` type must be first, then `orderEntry` with `module` type (to sort by `module-name`), finally `orderEntry` with `library` type (to sort by `name`) ? That's mostly what I want to know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this meets your requirements,  but you could explicitly select the ones you want to come first in a separate `xsl:apply-templates`, then select the others with a sort on their `type` attribute

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="orderEntry[@type='specific' or @type='other']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="orderEntry[@type!='specific' and @type!='other']">
   <xsl:sort select="@type" order="descending" />
   <xsl:sort select="@module-name" order="ascending" />
   <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Looking at the current expected output, it seems all the `type` attributes are in descending order, so you could simplify it to this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="orderEntry">
    <xsl:sort select="@type" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="@module-name" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="component">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::orderEntry)]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="orderEntry">
                <xsl:sort select="@type" order="descending" />
                <xsl:sort select="@module-name" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, if you actually wanted to sort on `type` attribute that were not in alphabetical order, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="orderEntry">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('specific,other,module,library',@type))" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:sort select="@module-name" order="ascending" />
    <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Thanks! This XSLT is OK. I just replace `<xsl:sort select="@type" order="descending" />` by `<xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('specific,other,module,library',@type))" order="ascending" />` as indicated, thanks!